# Constructing Correlated Wiener Processes

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

[Construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1frOH.png)

Hello. I'm reading the attached paper about the construction of correlated processes given a correlation matrix. But I am stuck on equation (2.23)  -- surely it should say $c_{ik} . c_{kj} = \rho_{ij}$ instead?

I must be mistaken -- and would be grateful if someone could explain (2.23).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting the transposition in the Cholesky decomposition. We have that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n c_{ik}(t) c_{jk}(t) dt = \sum_{k=1}^n (C_t)_{ik} (C_t^*)_{kj} dt  = (C_t C_t^*)_{ij} dt = \rho_{ij}(t) dt$$ 
The reason the indices have been reversed is that the second matrix in the matric product is transposed. Note that $\sum_{k=1}^n c_{ik}(t)c_{kj}(t) = (C_t^2)_{ij} \neq \rho_{ij}(t)$.

Comment: Thank you Rhys that clears things up!!!

Comment: This was very helpful!